# EntityValue returns CharacterEncodingError

Tags: warning-messages, entity

Whenever I try to use natural language-input, or even just call the EntityValue function, like in a Documentation example:

```
EntityValue[Entity["Bridge", "GoldenGateBridge::j6798"], "LongestSpan"]
```

I get the following error:

```
$CharacterEncoding::charcode: CloudObject`ToCharacterEncoding[TEXT/PLAIN,ISO8859-1] is not a valid character encoding. Possible settings are the names given by $CharacterEncodings or None. >>
```

And despite I try to do

```
$CharacterEncoding = "UTF-8"
```

I just can't make this work. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have Mathematica 10.4 and Windows 10.

Comment: Someone else reported the same problem [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/860392?p_p_auth=K3QbxmuU).  They restarted their machine and the problem went away.  However, they attributed it to the restart automatically resetting `$CharacterEncoding = "UTF-8"`, but it's unclear whether doing this manually without the restart (which you've already tried) would have worked for them .

Comment: @JessRiedel yes, I tried restarting, for me this is the default encoding

Comment: @PeterDam Have you reported the problem to Wolfram Support? They might be able to troubleshoot more thoroughly.